# Program not accepting all values from file

Tags: c

I posted a problem yesterday regarding a certain segment of my code. The aim was to basically scan in data values from a .dat file into an array, print the values whilst also counting how many values were in the file.

Sounds pretty simple, but my program only seemed to print a certain number of the values. More specifically, of a data file containing over 300000 values, it would only print the last 20000 and nothing else.

So I left it, finished the rest of my code and now it's the last part I have to sort. I've made a few changes and tried actually printing an output .dat file now so I can see what I'm getting. The code is below by the way.

Initally I assumed perhaps it was something related to the memory allocation of my array (was getting a segmentation error? when putting the whole code together) so I created an external function that counted the number of values instead (that works).

My only problem now is that it still only chooses to print 20000 values and then the rest are 0s. I was thinking perhaps it had something to do with the type but they all contain 7 dps in scientific notation. Here's a sample of some of the values:

```
   8.4730000e+01   1.0024256e+01
   8.4740000e+01   8.2065599e+00
   8.4750000e+01   8.3354644e+00
   8.4760000e+01   8.3379525e+00
   8.4770000e+01   9.8741315e+00
   8.4780000e+01   9.0966478e+00
   8.4790000e+01   9.4760274e+00
   8.4800000e+01   7.1199807e+00
   8.4810000e+01   7.1990172e+00
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong? I'm sorry for the long question, it's just been bugging me for the last day or so and no matter what I change nothing seems to help. Any kind of input would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count(int);

const char df[]="data_file.dat";
const char of[]="output_file.dat";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input, *output;
    int   i, N;
    float *array;

    N = count(i);

    input = fopen(df, "r");
    output = fopen(of, "w");

    array = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

    if((input != (FILE*) NULL) && (output != (FILE*) NULL))
    {
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            fscanf(input, "%e", &array[i]);
            fprintf(output, "%d %e\n", i, array[i]);
        }

        fclose(input);
        fclose(output);
    }
    else
        printf("Input file could not be opened\n");

    return(0);
}

int count(int i)
{
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(df, "r");

    int N = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        i = fgetc(input);
        if (i == EOF)
            break;
        ++N;
    }

    fclose(input);

    return(N);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just your terminal that can't handle this amount of text printed?

Comment: N seems to count characters, but then you use it to loop over lines in the file.  Each line will have several characters so this might explain why you get lots of 0 outputs?

Comment: On top of the fact that your `count()` counts characters, not values (or even lines), it doesn't appear that you're doing anything to skip over whitespace. Does using `fscanf(input, " %e", ...)` (note the space before the `%e`) make a difference?

Comment: Thank you both for replying. @H2CO3, I'm using the GCC compiler via CodeBlocks and I honestly don't know if that's the case. It certainly prints the correct number of values, but like I said after 20,000 of them they're all 0 which does seem suspicious.

Comment: @Peter de Rivaz, I thought that may be an issue yet I've tried it without an external function for N and using a while loop that terminates at the EOF yet I get exactly the same results.

Comment: @twalberg, I realise the count() function seems unnecessary and I have tried it without as mentioned above, this is kind of a last resort. It certainly counts the correct number of values so I think that should be OK. I am also concerned about the whitespace but I perhaps naively assumed my fscanf would cover that. I just tried putting the space before %e but the same result :(

Comment: If your file contained just one value, `count()` would return 14 (13 characters in the float + 1 newline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that `count()` doesn't count float values; it counts how many characters are in the file.  Then you try to loop and call `fscanf()` more times than there are values in the file.  The first times, `fscanf()` finds a float value and scans it; but once the loop reaches the end of file, `fscanf()` will be returning an EOF status.  It seems possible that `fscanf()` will set the float value to `0.0` when it returns EOF.

I suggest you rewrite so that you don't try to pre-count the float values.  Write a loop that just repeatedly calls `fscanf()` until it returns an EOF result, then break out of the loop and close the files.

P.S. If you are going to write a function like `count()`, you should pass in the filename as an argument instead of hard-coding it.  And your version of `count()` takes an integer argument but just ignores the value; instead, just declare a temp variable inside of `count()`.

EDIT: Okay, here is a complete working program to solve this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *in_file, *out_file;
    unsigned int i;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: this_program_name <input_file> <output_file>\n");
        return 1; // error exit with status 1
    }

    in_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!in_file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open input file '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1; // error exit with status 1
    }

    out_file = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (!out_file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open output file '%s'\n", argv[2]);
        return 1; // error exit with status 1
    }


    for (i = 0; ; ++i)
    {
        int result;
        float x;

        result = fscanf(in_file, "%e", &x);
        if (1 != result)
            break;

        fprintf(out_file, "%d %e\n", i, x);
    }

    return 0; // successful exit
}
```

Note that this version doesn't need to allocate a large array; it just needs a single temporary float variable.  Maybe your program will need to store all the float values.  In that case, write a `count()` function that uses a loop similar to the above loop, using `fscanf()` to count float values.

Also note that this program checks for errors after calling `fopen()` and `fscanf()`.

Comment: I think I understand where I have made several errors. Thank for your advice, I'll implement what you're suggesting (what I tried initally) and see what happens. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating far more floats in memory (N) than you need because your N is the number of *characters* in the file, not the number of values in it.
Also, how did you determine that there are 300000 values in the file?

Comment: I made a very silly error in assuming fgetc returned number of strings, not characters. The actually input is 20000 I've discovered, so it's scanning correctly but it's just not printing as many as I would like.